# Display Images from a File into Pictureboxes

Tags: image, vb6, picturebox

I have a folder called

`App.Path & "\Images"`

Inside of it I have 5 Images and in my `Form` I have also 5 `Pictureboxes`. Now my question is, How can I display them all one `PictureBox` per `Image` at a time? heres is my code so far

`Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture("Path")`

Heres what I've done so far

```
 Dim c         As Control
    Dim ImageLink As String

    With vs1

        For Each c In Form1
            For i = 1 To .Rows - 1

                If Len(ImageLink) > 0 Then ImageLink = ImageLink


                Debug.Print c.Picture
                Debug.Print .TextMatrix(i, .ColIndex("Image"))
                MsgBox .TextMatrix(i, .ColIndex("Image"))
                c.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\paul\Desktop\Gondola Monitoring System\Image\" & .TextMatrix(i, .ColIndex("Image")))

            Next
        Next
    End With
    Form1.Show
```

I try to write the filename in flexgrid and call it in each control.

TYSM for help

Answer (score 0):

```
Picture1.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Images\file1.jpg")
Picture2.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Images\file2.jpg")
Picture3.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Images\file3.jpg")
Picture4.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Images\file4.jpg")
Picture5.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Images\file5.jpg")
```

If this doesn't provide you with what you need, please provide more details on your requirements.

**EDIT**

Your code isn't going to work.  You are looping over all the controls, which will include any buttons, labels, etc, in addition to your picture controls, and for each control you are looping through all the rows of your grid.  One better approach would be to define the picture controls as an array (starting index from 1 to match your grid for loop), then the for index is used so that the grid rows and picture indexes match.  Something like this:

```
With vs1
    For i = 1 To .Rows - 1
        Picture1(i).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Users\paul\Desktop\Gondola Monitoring System\Image\" & .TextMatrix(i, .ColIndex("Image")))
    Next
End With
```